# Input Component doesn't support React useRef Hook on re-mounting the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-ref

I am using hooks for a login page where the text input is focused on the **component mount** after 1 second.
The below-mentioned code works fine for the **first mount**. If we come back on the login screen after log out, I am getting this error after 1 second. *(Error is mentioned below)*

**My code:***(It's just rough!! I hope you will understand)*

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';

function Login(props) {
....................
const inputRef = useRef(null);
.............................

useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(() => {
  inputRef.current.focus();
 }, 1000);
}, []);

......................
return(
.....................
<TextInput
        ref={inputRef}
        label="Enter your name"
/>

)

}

export default Login;
```

**Error:**

[image]

***Authentication flow:***

```
function RootNavigation(props) {
  const loginState = useSelector(state => state.LoginSlice.loginStatus);
  const otpLoginState = useSelector(state => state.OtpConfirmSlice.loginStatus);
  return (
    <>
      {loginState || otpLoginState ? <MyDrawer /> : <StartScreenNavigation />}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `autoFocus` prop here, like this

```
<TextInput
    ref={inputRef}
    label="Enter your name"
    autoFocus={true} // This will get focused it when it gets loaded.
/>
```

If you have a single input Box on the page then it's fine...But this will fail if you have multiple inputs with `autoFocus={true}` and in that case it will focus on the last `TextInput` component

Working Example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/autofocus-textinput)

Your `code` should then look like

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

function Login(props) {
  return <TextInput placeholder="Enter your name" autoFocus={true} />;
}

export default Login;
```

**To focus after 2 seconds**

You can add a listener in the screen like this

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Execute something here
      }, 2000);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

Then in your `Login` screen you can do like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Executed After 2 seconds');
        inputRef.current.focus();
        // Here input will get focused after 2 seconds
      }, 2000);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        ref={inputRef}
        placeholder="Enter your name here"
        style={{ padding: 10 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: Yes!! this works but i need a gap of 2 seconds after mounting.

Comment: Is `Login` a `screen`??

Comment: Yess Login is a screen

Comment: Perfect!.. Then my solution will do the job for you.

Comment: Also check the Snack again...It will make the input focus after two seconds

Comment: For the first mount, it's working fine. But after logout again it's giving me the same error.(For your code)

Comment: When you `logout` are you navigating away from `Login` screen??

Comment: How are you executing the logout..Show that..then maybe I can tell a better way

Comment:  About that, I am using two different stacks for user screens and login screens. I am using redux and on change of user state, I am deciding the screen Authentication Flow.https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Comment: I have updated!! once I hit logout the `loginState` changes to false and that takes me back to **Login Stack**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231945/discussion-between-satyam-and-kartikey-vaish).